# In Google Analytics, when sending an event, do I need to send "page_path" or does it automatically get it from the last "page_view"?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-events, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

When I send an even through Google Analytics, more specifically GA4, is that event automatically "linked" to a `page_path`?

I mean, if I send 2 events on `/page-a` and 4 events from `/page-b`, I need to be able to separate them by `page_path` in my Analytics reports.

```
gtag("event", "my_event", {
  custom_parameter: "custom_value",
  page_path: "/page-a" OR "/page-b"     // DO I NEED TO PASS THE PAGE_PATH PARAMETER ???
});
```

Do I need to pass the `page_path` parameter in order to be able to relate them to the pages that they were fired from?

Or do they automatically infer the `page_path` from the last `gtag("config")` command that sent a `page_view` hit?

Answer (score 1):

page_location is automatically sent on all events. I don't see page_path being sent at all but it is available in some reports including the analysis hub. I tested a few events and saw it was set. Maybe it is calculated.

Not sure what happens if you try to manually set it in the gtag.